# Combine columns from two text files

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How to create a new file merging the columns from two separate files
 with the same beginning information, but different number of lines

For example:

**File 1:**

```
*row*   *col*   *A*   
 1       0      23
 1       1      34
 1       2      34
```

---

**File 2:**

```
*row*   *col*   *B* 
 1       0      100
 1       2      110
```

---

**Merged file:**

```
*row*   *col*    *A*    *B*
 1       0       23     100              
 1       1       34
 1       2       34     110
```

Comment: Possible solution at U&L: [How to merge two files based on the matching of two columns?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/113898/251553) They don't address different number of _lines_ though.

Comment: Do the files include the headlines (`row/col/A/B`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {b[$1 $2] = $3; next} {$0 = $0 "\t" b[$1 $2]} 1' File2 File1
*row*  *col*  *A*  *B*
1      0      23   100
1      1      34
1      2      34   110
```

(Note that this will place an empty tab-separated field in the `*B*` position where there is no corresponding value in `File2`.)

Comment: Is there a way to fill the blank space with 0 for example?

Comment: @LarissaHelena sure - you just need to test whether `b[$1 $2]` is empty and if so print something else - there are several ways you could write that, for example changing `b[$1 $2]` to `(b[$1 $2] == "" ? 0 : b[$1 $2])`